# Set the selected index of select tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I set the default selected index of select tag using java script? My code working well, but I can't determine the default selected value (for example) the first value.

```
  var CompanySelect = document.getElementById("ManagingCompaniesSelect");
if (result && result.length > 0) {
    CompanySelect.options[CompanySelect.options.length] = new Option(_seletCompany, -1);

    for (var i = 0; i <= result.length-1; i++)
    { CompanySelect.options[CompanySelect.options.length] = new Option(result[i].ManagingCompanyName, result[i].MangingCompanyGUId); }
}




var txtManagingCompany = '#ManagingCompaniesSelect' + ' option[value=-1]';
$(txtManagingCompany).attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `selectedIndex` property.

**Example**

```
 CompanySelect.selectedIndex = 0;
 // will select the first option by default and so on..
```

Comment: I have added it up @mohkan

Comment: I mean the one where you are using the selectedIndex property.

Comment: @mohkan you can check it now

Comment: @Alaa: “It doesn't work”. On its on, that’s a useless comment. It’s more useful to describe what happens when you try the supplied code.